# SQL-Oracle: Difficulties in resolving basic problems

Tags: sql, oracle

Create a query to display the total number of employees and, of that total, the number of employees
hired in 2005, 2006, 2007, and 2008. Create appropiate column headings.

So far i have managed to do this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT employee_id) AS "Total",
   (CASE WHEN hire_date BETWEEN '01-01-2005' AND '31-12-2005' THEN '2005'
       WHEN hire_date BETWEEN  '01-01-2006' AND '31-12-2006' THEN '2006'
       WHEN hire_date BETWEEN  '01-01-2007' AND '31-12-2007' THEN '2007'
       WHEN hire_date BETWEEN  '01-01-2008' AND '31-12-2008' THEN '2008'
       ELSE 'Out of Range'
       END ) AS "Years"
FROM   employees
WHERE  hire_date BETWEEN '31-12-2005' AND '01-01-2008'
GROUP BY hire_date;
```

But the output is not as it should be. Can't upload pictures due to my low reputation to see exactly what i mean :). Anyway, any suggestions please?

Comment: I think you've misread the question. "total number of employees" e.g. Acme Inc has 500 employees. "and, of that total, ...". so out of those 500 employees, how many were hired in 05/06/07/08. e.g. "500 total, 10 in '05, 1 in '06, 30 in '07, 4 in '08"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should Use format like this `yyyy-MM-dd`

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT employee_id) AS "Total",
SUM( CASE WHEN hire_date BETWEEN '2005-01-01' AND '2005-12-31' THEN 1 else 0 end) as   
'2005', 
SUM( CASE WHEN hire_date BETWEEN '2006-01-01' AND '2006-12-31' THEN 1 else 0 end) as 
'2006',
SUM( CASE WHEN hire_date BETWEEN '2007-01-01' AND '2007-12-31' THEN 1 else 0 end) as 
'2007',
SUM( CASE WHEN hire_date BETWEEN '2008-01-01' AND '2008-12-31' THEN 1 else 0 end) as 
'2008',
SUM( CASE WHEN hire_date < '2005-01-01' OR  hire_date > '31-12-2008' 
THEN 1 else 0 end) as 
"Out of Range"
FROM   employees
```

Comment: It didn't work with that format you recommended me, i had to change it back due to my database format. I think i understood your method for solving problem this correctly. Thanks man, now it works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably change your query to something like

```
SELECT COUNT(employee_id) AS "Total",
SUM(case when hire_date BETWEEN '01-01-2005' AND '31-12-2005' THEN 1 else 0 end) as '2005',
SUM(case WHEN hire_date BETWEEN  '01-01-2006' AND '31-12-2006' THEN 1 else 0 end) as '2006',
SUM(case WHEN hire_date BETWEEN  '01-01-2008' AND '31-12-2008' THEN 1 else 0 end) as '2008',
SUM(case WHEN hire_date BETWEEN  '01-01-2007' AND '31-12-2007' THEN 1 else 0 end) as '2007'
FROM   employees
GROUP BY hire_date;
```